# CUPS 2.3.3op2 doesn't detect USB printer

Tags: debian, printing, printer, network-printer, cups

I'm experiencing a problem with my printing server based on CUPS. Around a week ago it stopped detecting my USB printer. Tried reintalling the OS, nothing changed. All commands outputs are from OS after reinstall.

OS info (Debian Bullseye):

```
~$ uname -a
Linux server 5.10.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.127-2 (2022-07-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

System info:

```
Host PC: HP t620 Thin Client
Printer: Brother HL-L5100DN
```

Tried fixing the issue for a long time now, but nothing works for me. Here are some command outputs I used to figure out the problem.

```
~# lpinfo -v
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network ipps
network ipp
network http
network socket
network lpd
serial serial:/dev/ttyUSB2?baud=230400
```

This serial thingy turned out to be my USB modem, for some reason it is detected as printer I think.

```
~# /usr/lib/cups/backend/usb
DEBUG: Loading USB quirks from "/usr/share/cups/usb".
DEBUG: Loaded 98 quirks.
DEBUG: list_devices
DEBUG: libusb_get_device_list=8
DEBUG: Failed to set alternate interface 0 for 04f9:007f: Broken pipe
```

Lsusb:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f9:007f Brother Industries, Ltd HL-L5100DN series
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and my solution was removing the `ipp-usb` package, may be give it a try.

Comment: Looked for an hour to find out why I couldn't print to an Epson from Fedora over USB.  No help anywhere regarding USB!  This finally worked, not sure why.  Probably blocking it somehow.  Removed it and printer came alive immediately.  Also confirm you're in `lp` group.  Thank you.